# Get argument value from string input

Tags: c#, web-services, string, arguments, restful-authentication

How do I create a class method to get the argument from a string input?

string value GetArugmentValueByName (string input, string name)

**Example**

```
myInput="code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp6&
client_id=21302922996.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=XTHhXh1SlUNgvyWGwDk1EjXB&
redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/back&
grant_type=authorization_code";
```

If I do this

```
string myGrantType = GetArugmentValueByName(myInput, "grant_type");
```

the value of myGrantType should equal "authorization_code"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) to parse out the params into a name value collection, then index into that for the param you are looking for.

```
public string GetArgumentValueByName(string queryString, string paramName)
{
    var paramCol = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
    return paramCol[paramName] ?? string.Empty;        
}
```

Comment: Modified my code, NameValueCollection returns null if you index it with a non-existing key. So you don't need to check the key set to determine if paramName exists first.